# Problems with nl2br() and mysqli_real_escape_string() working together

Tags: php

I'm trying to use the php nl2br() function to convert \r\n characters into `<br>` tags in an email. There seems to be some sort of conflict when I try to use it with mysqli_real_escape_string().  I can verify seperately that the mysqli_real_escape_string function() is giving the proper output, and that the nl2br() function is properly converting the appropriate characters to `<br>` tags, but they won't work together. Why?!

I can confirm nl2br works:

```
    $message= "This\r\nis\n\ra\nstring\r";
    $message= nl2br($message);
    echo($message);
```

output:

`"This is a string"`

I can confirm mysqli_real_escape_string() works:

```
//assume $_POST['message'] = "this is a string"
$message = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['message']); 
echo($message);
```

output:

```
This\r\nis\n\ra\nstring\r
```

When I use them together:

```
$message = nl2br(mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['message']));
```

Output:

```
This\r\nis\r\na\r\nstring
```

Comment: Why would you use `nl2br` on a string returned by `mysqli_real_escape_string`?

Comment: escaping should be the **LAST** operation you perform on a string. Doing further manipulations of an escaped string can actually UNDO the escaping and open you up to sql injection attacks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mysqli_real_escape_string` escapes newlines, so `nl2br` can't find them (obviously).

A simple script to demonstrate this:

```
$ cat test.php
$c = mysqli_connect('192.168.33.10', 'root', '');
print("Hello\nWorld\n");
print(mysqli_real_escape_string($c, "Hello\nWorld"));

$ php test.php | hexdump -C  
00000000  48 65 6c 6c 6f 0a 57 6f  72 6c 64 0a 48 65 6c 6c  |Hello.World.Hell|
00000010  6f 5c 6e 57 6f 72 6c 64                           |o\nWorld|
```

As you can see, the newline character (`0x0a`) has been replaced by the string `\n` (`0x5c` and `0x6e`).

So, call `nl2br` first:

```
$message = mysqli_real_escape_string(nl2br($_POST['message']), $connection);
```

Comment: That's working half way. So now it's creating the carriage return, but it's still keeping the /r/n at the beginning of each line.

Comment: Actually, I figured it out.  I performed this function after escaping the string:  $message = str_replace('\r\n','', $message);

I ran into trouble with that... apparently there's a difference between using single and double quotes around the '\r\n'.  "\r\n" doesn't work.

Comment: @user2755541 Yes, in PHP, only double-quoted (`"`) are parsed for variables & escape characters, single quoted strings (`'`) are not; see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php